# What is the structure of Neural Networks for mean and standard deviation?

Tags: mean, standard-deviation

I am curious whether there is a certain neural network that automatically calculates mean and standard deviation.

Suppose there is dataset with one input variable x. There is 6 elements {1,4,5,2,6,2}. I am curious if I form a autoencoder with one bottle neck and one bias, linear of activation function, does this neural network calculate mean and standard deviation automatically?

Comment: Do you mean inputting the whole set at once into the network (that's how I'd understand your autoencoder idea, having 6 inputs), or feeding the elements sequentially, one-by-one to a single-input network (since you say to have "one input variable")?

Comment: The second. The network has a single-input, so we have to feed the element one-by-one sequentially.